# YouTube Data API Snippet.Description differs from YouTube Studio's Description

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I've been working on a tool to programmatically update my video descriptions and have ran in to an oddity.

When using the API to update the snippet.description the description changes in the API, the YouTube front-end website, and the iOS YouTube Studio app immediately but the web-based YouTube Studio still shows the old description.

If I change the description in the web-based YouTube Studio it saves as expected and the new description shows up everywhere.

Is this a bug or a feature on their side or something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out @joshbuilds?